# Error: 'use_package' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'

Tags: r, package

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting around this error? I'm new to creating packages and am currently following Hadley Wickham's guide.

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html

Comment: That post might be outdated, this function is now part of [usethis](https://cran.r-project.org/package=usethis) package.

Comment: In fact this is already fixed on GitHub; they haven't published the new version yet on the site, it seems: https://github.com/hadley/r-pkgs/blob/master/metadata.Rmd#L105

Comment: reposted zx8754 and MichaelChirico comments in an answer to make it easier for users to find this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I deal with "'someFunction' is not an exported object from 'namespace:somePackage'" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506879/how-should-i-deal-with-somefunction-is-not-an-exported-object-from-namespace)

Answer (score 3):

To copy the comments of @zx8754, `use_package` is now part of the `usethis` package. And per the comment from @MichaelChirico, Hadley's book is updated on [github](https://github.com/hadley/r-pkgs/blob/master/metadata.Rmd#L105), but has not yet been re-published.